# Get value from a slider to control a servo with Arduino

Tags: html, arduino, ethernet, servo

I have a question. Can I get a value from a slider on my HTML page to control the angle of a servo connected to the Arduino board?

I am able to get a value from a button, for example information like: `on`/`off`, it is easy to get it, but I'm not able to get a value from a range 0-150 when it changes. I am using an Arduino and an ethernet shield.
Can someone help me?

My slider code:

```
client.print("< input type='range' min='1' max='150' name=greVal value=greTemp oninput='showValue1(this.value)' >");
client.println("< span id='range1'>0< /span>");
client.println("<script type='text/javascript'>\r\nfunction showValue1(newValue)\ \n{\r\ndocument.getElementById('range1').innerHTML=newValue;\r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n");
```

Code of buttons on/off, i would like to make something like this with servo.. I mean put value of slider in `href`, after IP

```
client.println("< a href=\"/?on\"\">on</a>");
client.println("< a href=\"/?off\"\">off</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it happen automatically, without clicking a link, you can change your `showValue1` function and make it change location. Check the snippet below.

```
function updateRange(newValue) {
     window.location = "http://localhost/index.php?range=" + newValue;
}
```

You can also do the same after button click by wrapping your inputs in `form` tag and setting it action to `get` instead of `post`. Submitting would result with adding inputs with values to your URL.